# What't correct meaning of this "Trust me" according to the context?

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context

wisers,

I've got a question.
You see, for example. Hal find the pencil for Jim before the exam.
Jim speak to Hal, "Thanks very much, Hal. Trust me to lose my pencil just before this big exam...".

I consider it's because Jim has a poor memory, always lose some important stuff, so this "Trust me" means ***Hal foresee Jim*** will lose something before the exam. Correct or not?

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: [Please review your grammar. It is basically all wrong. Thank you.]

Comment: _Trust me to VP_ is an idiom for "I'm so unlucky/clumsy that I even VP". It's a self-deprecation to fend away bad luck by admitting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Trust me to lose my pencil

= **You can** trust me to lose my pencil. ->

= **I always lose my pencil, so you can rely on me** to lose my pencil. ->

= It is typical of me to lose my pencil.

The construction is use with "me" and "us" in order to admit one's own typical negligence, and with other nouns and pronouns to indicate someone/something else's negligence:

A: Who drove my car last? The door is scratched!

B: John.

A: Trust John to have an accident - he's a useless driver.

A: Did you buy an milk at the shop?

B: No, they didn't have any.

A: Trust the shop to have none - the manager's useless.